# Using Nouveau drives on Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I'm using Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon on my new PC I built. It has an intel i7 chip with integrated graphics but I want to use my GeForce GTX graphics card to as my display. I'm fine using the Nouveau drivers but they don't show up in my Driver Manager. 
How can I install the appropriate Nouveau drivers on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, you'll likely want to go with the drivers that NVidia actually provides to get the most out of your rig.

Get your card's specific drivers [here](https://www.geforce.com/drivers).

If you would actually prefer Nouveau, instructions (old) are located [here](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/UbuntuPackages/).